# Adding admob widget hiding the button

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to have the admob ad on the bottom of activity inside the tablerow. The problem is when I am adding the admob widget is is not displaying the button below it. Initially when the ad is not loaded it shows the button but as soon as it shows the ad the button disappears.
Below is the code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/outerlinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/storycontentheader"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="2dip"
                        android:lineSpacingExtra="10dip"
                        android:text="Curteous Coutney Walsh gifts World Cup Final to Pakistan"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="25dip"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:fontFamily="calibri"
                         />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/storycontentauthor"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="2dip"
                        android:text="Martin Arthur | 5 people voted this story\n"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="12dip"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/storyTags"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="2dip"
                        android:text="Martin Arthur | 5 people voted this story\n"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="12dip"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/storyImage"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/storycontent"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:lineSpacingExtra="10dip"
                        android:padding="10dip"
                        android:text="content"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:fontFamily="calibri"
                        android:textSize="16dip" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
  <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/footer_tablerow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <com.google.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="XXXXXXXXXX"
                ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/footer_tablerow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


   <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lastUpdated"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="2dip"
                        android:text="Martin Arthur | 5 people voted this story\n"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="12dip"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/back_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:text="Back"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The button which disappears is back_btn.
Can you please help me on this.

Regards,
Amandeep

Comment: give gravity right|bottom

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/outerlinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent".
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/storycontentheader"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="calibri"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="10dip"
                android:padding="2dip"
                android:text="Curteous Coutney Walsh gifts World Cup Final to Pakistan"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="25dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/storycontentauthor"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="2dip"
                android:text="Martin Arthur | 5 people voted this story\n"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="12dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/storyTags"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="2dip"
                android:text="Martin Arthur | 5 people voted this story\n"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="12dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/storyImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/icon" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/storycontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="calibri"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="10dip"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:text="content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="16dip" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="XXXXXXXXXX"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lastUpdated"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="2dip"
            android:text="Martin Arthur | 5 people voted this story\n"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="12dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/back_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="Back"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining what was the problem and what is the solution in few lines?

Answer (score 0):

Use `LinearLayout` instead of `TableLayout` for footer layout. Replace the following XML portion...

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/footer_tablerow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="XXXXXXXXXX"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/footer_tablerow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lastUpdated"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="2dip"
            android:text="Martin Arthur | 5 people voted this story\n"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="12dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/back_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="Back"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

with the following XML portion...

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="XXXXXXXXXX"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer_tablerow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lastUpdated"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="2dip"
            android:text="Martin Arthur | 5 people voted this story\n"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="12dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/back_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="Back"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```